# Including a static library in a GBDK C project (GBExtended)

Tags: c, sdcc, gbdk

I want to use the [GBExtended library](http://www.tensi.eu/thomas/programming/gameboy/gbextended.html) in my game but I am having difficulty understanding how I would include the library.

I can see that the GBExtended library (at least from the loderunner example source) contains the directories `includes/`, `lib/` and `src/` and the file which I need to include is `lib/gbext.lib`.

I would assume that you would have to include the library in your files as needed:

```
#include <gbextended/screen.h>
# etc ...
```

What flags do you have to pass to the `lcc` compiler so that it will include these libraries? I'm having trouble identifying this from the examples.

Comment: Look for files name `libfoo.so` or `libfoo.a` in `lib/`.  Add `-lfoo` to LDFLAGS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SDCC you can use the -l flag (lowercase L) to specify a library to be included, and the -L flag (uppercase L) to specify the directory from which the files can be found.

You also have to use -I (uppercase I) to specify where the header files are located.